# how to copy directory with all file from c:\\xxx\yyy to c:\\zzz\ in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been trying to use "copytree(src,dst)", however I couldn't since the destination folder should exists at all.Here you can see the small piece of code I wrote:

```
def copy_dir(src,dest):
    import shutil
    shutil.copytree(src,dest)

copy_dir('C:/crap/chrome/','C:/test/')
```

and this is the error I m getting as I expected...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\MMS-Auto\copy.py", line 5, in        <module>
copy_dir('C:/crap/chrome/','C:/test/')   
File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\workspace\MMS-Auto\copy.py", line 3, in copy_dir
shutil.copytree(src,dest)
File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 174, in copytree
os.makedirs(dst)
File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 157, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists:    'C:/test/'
```

Here is my question is there a way I could achieve the same result without  creating my own copytree function?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do? Overwrite the files? Leave the original in place if a file allready exists?

Comment: would be enough to just copy them over, however I might want to add add such a functionality later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [`errno`](http://docs.python.org/library/errno.html) for possible errors. You can use `.copytree()` first, and then when there is error, use `shutil.copy`.

From: http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree

> If exception(s) occur, an Error is raised with a list of reasons.

So then you can decide what to do with it and implement your code to handle it.

```
import shutil, errno

def copyFile(src, dst):
    try:
        shutil.copytree(src, dst)
    # Depend what you need here to catch the problem
    except OSError as exc: 
        # File already exist
        if exc.errno == errno.EEXIST:
            shutil.copy(src, dst)
        # The dirtory does not exist
        if exc.errno == errno.ENOENT:
            shutil.copy(src, dst)
        else:
            raise
```

About `.copy()`: http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy

> Copy the file src to the file or directory dst. If dst is a directory,
>   a file with the same basename as src is created (or overwritten) in
>   the directory specified. Permission bits are copied. src and dst are
>   path names given as strings.

**Edit:** Maybe also look into [`distutils.dir_util.copy_tree`](http://docs.python.org/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.dir_util.copy_tree)

Comment: inside the if statement you didn't call anything... what should I add there?

Comment: ok thanks, anyway I'm getting "WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:/test/'"

Comment: Edit: If the file exist `EEXIST`, then use `.copy()`, it should overwrite them.

Answer (score 15):

### Notice:

`distutils` [has been deprecated and will be removed in Python 3.12](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#distutils-deprecated). Consider looking for other answers at this question if you are looking for a post-3.12 solution.

---

### Original answer:

I used the `distutils` package to greater success than the other answers here.

http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.dir_util

The `distutils.dir_util.copy_tree` function works very similarly to `shutil.copytree` except that `dir_util.copy_tree` will just overwrite a directory that exists instead of crashing with an Exception.

Replace:

```
import shutil
shutil.copytree(src, dst)
```

with:

```
import distutils.dir_util
distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(src, dst)
```

Comment: `DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
  from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree`

Answer (score 1):

I have a little work around that check whether there is a directory of the same name in the location first before doing the shutil.copytree function. Also it only copies directories with a certain wildcard. Not sure if that is needed to answer the question but I thought to leave it in there.

```
import sys
import os
import os.path
import shutil 


src="/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/_Jonatha/itmsp_source/"
dst="/Volumes/VoigtKampff/Temp/_Jonatha/itmsp_drop/"


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
    for dir in dirs:
        if dir.endswith('folder'):
            print "directory to be moved: %s" % dir
            s = os.path.join(src, dir)
            d = os.path.join(dst, dir)
            if os.path.isdir(d):
                print "Not copying - because %s is already in %s" % (dir, dst)
            elif not os.path.isdir(d):
                shutil.copytree(s, d)
                print "Copying %s to %s" % (dir, dst)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this depends on the exact version of python you have, but when i call shutil.copytree.**doc** i get this:

> Recursively copy a directory tree using copy2().
>
> The destination directory must not already exist.
>
> XXX Consider this example code rather than the ultimate tool.

This explains the error you are getting. You could probably use [distutils.dir_util.copy_tree](http://docs.python.org/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.dir_util.copy_tree) instead.

Comment: I don't want to add anything to python itself, although if I won't be able to do it otherwise ,I'll go for it

Comment: You mean you don't want to import any library? You imported shutil, you can just as well write `import distutils`.

Comment: Sorry I misread the python documentation, thank it works... thanks again