# copy_tree not copying sub directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, copytree

Using Python 3.8 on Windows 10 OS. The first time I run copy_tree it works perfectly, i.e. all files and sub-directories are copied over as expected.

When I manually delete the newly copied directory from the destination and run copy_tree again (within 1 minute from deleting the initial destination directory created by copy_tree), it will copy everything but the sub-directories. Note that there is no content within these sub-folders.

Is there a timeframe where a deleted folder is not technically deleted?

EDIT:
Here are my functions:

```
def isFolder(path):
    return os.path.isdir(path) if os.path.exists(path) else False

def copyFolderContent(srcFolder, destFolder):
    srcFolderOK = isFolder(srcFolder)
    destFolderOK = isFolder(destFolder)

    if srcFolderOK and destFolderOK:
        return copy_tree(srcFolder, destFolder)
    else:
        return None
```

The source directory looks like this:

```
SourceParentFolder
   -> ChildFolder
```

The destination directory looks like this:

```
DestinationParentFolder
   (no contents)
```

After running copy_tree the destination directory is:

```
DestinationParentFolder
   -> ChildFolder
```

Then, after manually deleting "ChildFolder" and running copy_tree within approximately one minute:

```
DestinationParentFolder
   (no contents)
```

The expectation is that "ChildFolder" is copied into DestinationParentFolder, but this does not happen unless a significant amount of time has passed.

Comment: It may be useful to add the `copy_tree` command you're executing, so we can attempt to reproduce it. What arguments are you using?

Comment: Edited original question to include more details

Answer (score 2):

I am having a very similar, perhaps identical, problem. After some testing, it seems the issue might partly be with my IDE, Spyder.

### The Issue

I have two directories `/test/a` and `/test/x`. I want to copy the contents of `a` into `x`. I want preserve as much metadata as possible, and I don't want my script to fail for existing files ([as was the case in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1868714/15426433)), so I'm trying to use `distutils.dir_util.copy_tree()`.

`a` contains the following files and subdirectories:

```
+---a
    |   
    \---b
        |   testfile1.txt
        |   
        \---c
                testfile2.txt
                testfile3.txt
```

Yesterday, I created a new anaconda environment with Python 3.9.2 and Spyder 4.2.3.

I ran the following script in Spyder:

```or-tag-here
from pathlib import Path
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree

src = Path.cwd() / 'a'
dst = Path.cwd() / 'x'


copy_tree(str(src), str(dst), preserve_times=True, update=False)
```

The first time I run the script, all of `a`'s contents are copied into `x`.

If I delete `x` and re-run the script, a new `x` is created, the contents of `a` are not copied, and the following errors are thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Joseph\computer\Anaconda3\envs\sandbox3\lib\distutils\file_util.py", line 41, in _copy_file_contents
    fdst = open(dst, 'wb')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Joseph\\test\\x\\b\\c\\testfile2.txt'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Joseph\test\troubleshoot-copy_tree-0.2.py", line 14, in <module>
    copy_tree(str(src), str(dst), preserve_times=True, update=False)

  File "C:\Users\Joseph\computer\Anaconda3\envs\sandbox3\lib\distutils\dir_util.py", line 157, in copy_tree
    copy_tree(src_name, dst_name, preserve_mode,

  File "C:\Users\Joseph\computer\Anaconda3\envs\sandbox3\lib\distutils\dir_util.py", line 157, in copy_tree
    copy_tree(src_name, dst_name, preserve_mode,

  File "C:\Users\Joseph\computer\Anaconda3\envs\sandbox3\lib\distutils\dir_util.py", line 161, in copy_tree
    copy_file(src_name, dst_name, preserve_mode,

  File "C:\Users\Joseph\computer\Anaconda3\envs\sandbox3\lib\distutils\file_util.py", line 151, in copy_file
    _copy_file_contents(src, dst)

  File "C:\Users\Joseph\computer\Anaconda3\envs\sandbox3\lib\distutils\file_util.py", line 43, in _copy_file_contents
    raise DistutilsFileError(

DistutilsFileError: could not create 'C:\Users\Joseph\test\x\b\c\testfile2.txt': No such file or directory
```

The error seems to be caused by _copy_file_contents, which is trying to open and write a new file where none exists. This doesn't make sense to me, because there shouldn't be a file there in the first place. See [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45098954/15426433) for a very similar problem, but with `shutil.copytree()` instead.

### What I tried

I tried deleting `x` again, then exiting out of Spyder, starting a new anaconda terminal session, opening Spyder again, and re-running the script. Everything works as expected (`x` is created, and `a`'s contents are copied into it). If I subsequently delete `x` and re-run the script, `x` is created and then the same errors are thrown. I don't know why restarting the Anaconda prompt and Spyder solves the problem for the first script run, but I was able to reproduce this multiple times.

I tried moving `a` and my script file into a new parent directory, and the script worked again (created `x`, copied all of `a`, etc). In the new location, I then deleted `x` and re-ran the script. `x` was created and then the same errors were thrown.

I then deleted `x`, exited out of Spyder, and started IDLE from the Anaconda prompt. I ran the script in IDLE and it worked the first time. I deleted `x` and re-ran the script, and it worked again. I did this several more times and it worked each time.

Why is my script working in IDLE but not in Spyder?

My apologies for my ridiculously long answer/question. I didn't want to post a separate question, as this sounded like a duplicate. Hopefully, this issue will get some more attention.

System Info: Windows 10, Python 3.9.2, Spyder 4.2.3